# Will my new drive fit in my laptop?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ssd

My laptop is a ASUS K53E

My current dive is
Height 9.5mm Width 69.75mm Length 100.3mm

The new drive is
Height 7.00 Width 69.85 Length 100.00

My question is is the new drive to wide?

Comment: **10 mm is unlikely to make a difference.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll be fine... It's the same form factor

The actual standard width is 69.9 mm

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive

See the 2.5" form factor section